# NSMutableDataのインスタンスがiPad(iOS7.0.4)でのみリークする

Tags: objective-c, iphone

AudioUnit を使って音声の録音、再生を行なうプログラムを作成しているのですが、以下のようなバグに遭遇しました。色々手を尽くしては見たものの一向に改善しなかったため、質問させていただきます。

録音側のAURenderCallbackStructに設定したコールバック関数 `AURenderCallback` 内中段の `NSMutableData *data` でメモリリークを起こしているようです。(`Instruments` の`Allocations` はずっと右肩上がりになっています：2.5KB/秒)

色々調査した結果分かった事↓です。

- (中略) 部分を削除しても現象に変化はありません
- `AudioProcessor *rec`、`OSStatus status` の行を削除しても現象に変化はありません
- `NSMutableData *data` を削除すると `Allocations` はすぐに一定になります
- `NSMutableData *data` を `int` や `NSData`, `NSArray` に変更すると `Allocation` はすぐに一定になります。
- `NSMutableDataやNSMutableArray`, `NSObject` では `Allocation` は一定にならず上昇をし続けたままになります
- この現象はiPad mini (iOS 7.0.4) でのみ確認できていて、iPhone 4s (iOS7.1.1) では発生しませんでした。

```
OSStatus AURenderCallback(void *inRefCon,
                         AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                         const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                         UInt32 inBusNumber,
                         UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                         AudioBufferList *ioData)
{    
    AudioProcessor *rec = (__bridge AudioProcessor *) inRefCon;

    OSStatus status = AudioUnitRender([rec audioUnit], ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, &testbufferList);


    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    /*
        ~(中略)~
    */
    return noErr;
}
```

以上、ご教示ください。

Answer (score 1):

私はMacのAudioUnitはそれなりに知っていますがObjective-Cの
メモリ管理システムにはあまり詳しくない、という者です。

で、このソースは一見しただけでリークしそうな感じがする実装になっています。
allocは、メモリを確保するためのメソッドなので、呼ばれるたびに
メモリを確保しますが、開放されている様子がないからです。
AURenderCallbackはかなりの頻度で実行されるので
メモリ使用量が増えていくだろうな、というのがソースをみただけで想像できます。

そもそも、AURenderCallback内でメモリ確保の処理を実行するのは
あまり良い戦略ではないので、NSMutableData* dataをAURenderCallback内で
はallocしないように処理を修正することをおすすめします。

やり方はいろいろとあると思いますが、私ならばAURenderCallbackの引数として渡されてくる
AudioProcessor側でallocしておき、AURenderCallbackで使うように実装します。
このソースからだとAURenderCallback以外の部分がどうなっているか不明なので、
具体的なソースは書きませんが、AURenderCallback内ではメモリ確保の処理はできないことを
前提にプログラムを書いたほうが良いことが多いです。

Comment: コールバック内でメモリ確保することの是非はともかく、ARCを使っていれば明示的に解放することはない（むしろしてはならない）のではないでしょうか。 http://cx5software.sakura.ne.jp/blog/2011/12/31/objective-c-memory_management_by_arc/